# PowerBI - Conditionally format a date column relative to todays date

Tags: powerbi

I have a report, updated on a daily basis, that provides me with a list of remote devices connected to our server.

A date column tells me the last date (and time) that a remote device sent data.
I want to conditionally format the column so that, if the last date is:

- Today's date: the cell is green
- Yesterday's date: the cell is yellow
- Up to 30 days old: the cell is orange
- older than 30 days: the cell is red
- empty: the cell is empty

I've had a small degree of success in progressing towards my goal, but the colours are the wrong way round and I'm struggling with the "if" syntax. I can get today's date displaying yellow and every other date displaying green - but, to be honest, I've no idea quite how !!

[Last data seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXkCX.png)

This is what I've done so far...

I have created a measure "flag3" as below (with the intention of showing green for today, orange 1 day old and red for 2 days old)

```
flag3 = if(DATEDIFF(TODAY(),SELECTEDVALUE(DeviceStatus[Column1.lastDataRecordTime]),DAY),1,
    (if(DATEDIFF(TODAY()-1,SELECTEDVALUE(DeviceStatus[Column1.lastDataRecordTime]),DAY),2,
        (if(DATEDIFF(TODAY()-2,SELECTEDVALUE(DeviceStatus[Column1.lastDataRecordTime]),DAY),3)))))
```

And I have created conditional formatting based on background colour, 
formatted by rules, 
based on field flag3

If the value is 1 - then green
If it's 2 - then orange
If it's 3 - then red

[Conditional Formatting based on Background Colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRmce.png)

As I've said previously- it's sort of working but the colours are the wrong way round and I'm struggling with syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a DATEDIFF formula - `DATEDIFF(TODAY(),FIRSTDATE('Table_Name'[Date_Column]),DAY)` without an if function and use it in conditional formatting with following conditions:

- greater than -10000 and less than -30
- greater than -30 and less than
- -1 euqal to -1
- equal to 0
- greater than 0 and less than 10000

Note: Make sure to replace **Table_Name** and **Date_Column** with your respective information

Example screenshot below:

[image: Conditional Formatting]